# How To Implement Javascript Polyline Collision Detection

Tags: javascript, collision, polyline

I currently have a JavaScript platformer game. I have created a polygon-polygon collision detection with a response, using the SAT method portrayed on many other websites.

I have also created a function inside the Polygon constructor that will return either the sides exposed to the top of the polygon or the sides exposed to the bottom of the polygon, depending on which direction is chosen. The array that is returned contains many different Vectors, which will be explained more elaborately later.

The current code looks a bit like this:

```
Polygon.prototype.getSidesOn = function(dir) {
  if (dir === "top" || dir === "bottom") {
    var result = [], start = false, stop = false, elen = 
this.calcPoints.length, e = 0, f = 0, point, next, prevX, prevY, directionX,   directionY;
    while (!stop) {
      if (e >= 5*elen) {return;}
      f = e%elen;
      prev = f-1 < 0 ? this.calcPoints[elen-1] : this.calcPoints[f-1];
      point = this.calcPoints[f];
      prevX = directionX;
      prevY = directionY;
      directionX = point.x > prev.x ? "right" : point.x < prev.x ? "left" : directionX;
      directionY = point.y < prev.y ? "up" : point.y > prev.y ? "down" : directionY;
      if (prevX !== directionX && prevX && prevY) {
        if (!start) {
          start = dir === "top" ? directionY === "up" : directionY === "down";
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (start) {
        if (point.x !== prev.x) {
          if (!result.length) {
            result.push(new Vector(prev.x,prev.y),new 
Vector(point.x,point.y));
          } else {
            result.push(new Vector(point.x,point.y));
          }
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      e++;
    }
    return result;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

I understand that it is a bit messy, but that is not a worry as I will optimise it later.

Basically, it works on ONLY convex polygons (I mean the word "convex" as in a triangle or a shape that does not go back into itself). Anyway, it works because of the fact that all convex polygons only have two points where the adjacent sides are facing the opposite X direction.

Anyway, the array that is outputted looks a bit like this:

```
//[Vector,Vector,Vector,Vector...]
```

that is not what it actually looks like, but basically, it outputs an array of Vectors for each point detected.

What I need to implement is a way to detect collision between two of these polylines. Unlike the polygon-polygon collision detection system, there does not need to be a response vector, and instead, the code should output either a "true" or "false" bool.

The only way that I can currently think of doing this is as follows:

```
function PolylinePolyline(line1,line2) {
  var i, ilen = line1.length, j, jlen = line2.length;
  for (i = 0; i < ilen; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < jlen; j++) {
      var point1 = line1[i];
      var point2 = i+1 < ilen ? line1[i+1] : line1[0];
      var point3 = line2[j];
      var point4 = j+1 < jlen ? line2[j+1] : line2[0];
      var line01 = new line(point1,point2);
      var line02 = new line(point3,point4);
      if (LineLine(line01,line02) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And although this works, it is very expensive to use if the lines are, let's say, 5 points long, and I have to detect collision between 4 of them. I would prefer an alternative that returns true if they are colliding and false if not. I will not explain why I need this, as it is a bit abstract but an example of a polyline would be this:

[Note that the polylines are convex-shaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5LGS.png)

Comment: You can save some time by creating the lines just once for every polygon so that ` new line(point1,point2)` is executed just once. It isn't the radical breakthrough you are looking for, I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your collision search by defining (pseudo random) infinite length lines that go between two polygons such that the line splits up the polygons into 3 sets: above, below and colliding. Because they are dvidied by the line, you know that all above do not collide with all below. Repeat this a few times until you have a low number of undecided polygon pairs, then apply your old algorithm to the remaining pairs.

You can find (pseudo random) infinite length lines by calculating the normal at the middle of the line connecting the centers of two polygons in your set of polygons.

Comment: I don't understand. Only polygons can be convex. And the algorithm I am proposing works for lines as well.

Comment: You can still use the dividing line algorithm to separate two polylines if each line has several segments.